# How can we share Credentials between two Jenkins masters

Tags: jenkins

We have two Jenkins masters running in two different machines. They are not related to each other. Is it possible to share Credentials between the two masters?

Comment: Your questions lacks details . Is this about single sign on? or Sharing jenkins secrets credentials? Try  https://plugins.jenkins.io/hashicorp-vault-plugin/ for latter

Comment: Its about sharing jenkins secret credentials. Will the plug-in work??

Comment: yes. Please try and  ask specific questions. Your company may have different solution for managing such credentials. (such as Thycotic secret server)